# how to select previous rows in data frame?

Tags: r, dataframe, subset

Let's say we have a data frame:

```
df <- data.frame(a=1:5, b=4:8)
```

How can I subset by the previous rows? For example, if I am at row 3, I want to get the values of row 1 and row 2, if I am at row 4, I want to get the values row 2 and row 3. How can I do this in R?

Comment: How many previous rows? From your post, it seems two.

Comment: Not clear but you may look at `head` or  [lag](http://www.inside-r.org/packages/cran/Hmisc/docs/Lag) or [shift](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table)

Comment: @Pascal yep, let's say 2 rows for this example. I am hoping for a general solutions for something like this

Comment: This makes no sense to me. The phrase "subset by previous row" is not operationally defined. If the question is how to subtract 1 or 2 from the current index in a for-loop then it appears trivial.

Comment: using a for loop is trivial, but slow. Using lag from zoo allows vectorisation.

Comment: @BondedDust you are right, I think my question is too vague, I'm thinking of using it in the context of data manipulation (using packages such as dplyr), for example creating a new column and taking the mean of previous values..the lag suggestion seems promising, I will give that a try

Comment: When you say "if I am at", it is reminiscent of Excel mode thinking.

Comment: @plafort haha yes, I realize that. just didn't know the best way to describe it

Answer (score 1):

Using the `zoo` library (be careful, as base lag works differently):

```
library(zoo)
df <- zoo(df)
df[lag(df$b, -1) == 4, ]

  a b
2 2 5

df[lag(df$b, -2) == 4, ]

  a b
3 3 6
```

Answer (score 1):

This may be too simple but if you want a generic answer, this may be just right:

```
# create your data.frame, not using 'df' as it is an R function name
myDF <- data.frame(a=1:5, b=4:8)

# you know you "are at row 4"
i <- 4

# so you can get the previous two rows simply with
myDF[ ( i - 2:1 ), ]
  a b
2 2 5
3 3 6
```